# Styling some parts of my React JSX rendered elements with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, styles

I have an array of data that I'm mapping through in my small react project to render the contents of the data into the browser. But my problem is that I need to style some parts of these rendered contents and not all. Each of the CSS properties I'm applying is applicable to all the P tags. For Example, in the code below, The style will be applicable to Was, to Birthday in the second item, and so on...

Below is my CSS code.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
const data = [
  {
    details: 'Yesterday was his birthday'
  },
  {
    details: 'Today is my birthday'
  },
  {
    details: 'I cant\'t remember my birthday date'
  }
]

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>I need Help</h1>
      <h2>Please How do i style some parts of my rendered details</h2>
      {
        data.map((detail)=>(
          <p>{detail.details}</p>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `highlight` prop to your array elements and split the sentence by that prop. Then, put the split word in its own `span` between the pieces.

```
export default function App() {
const data = [
  {
    details: 'Yesterday was his birthday',
    highlight: 'was'
  },
  {
    details: 'Today is my birthday',
    highlight: 'birthday'
  },
  {
    details: 'I cant\'t remember my birthday date',
    highlight: 'date'
  }
]

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>I need Help</h1>
      <h2>Please How do i style some parts of my rendered details</h2>
      {data.map((datum) => {
        const pieces = datum.details.split(datum.highlight);
        return (
          <p key={datum.details}>
            {pieces[0]}
            <span style={{ backgroundColor: "#FF0" }}>{datum.highlight}</span>
            {pieces[1]}
          </p>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please your solution is applying to all the elements. All I want is a part of the p tag and not all the words of that p tag.

Comment: @OluwafemiAkinyemi I updated my answer, this should do what you need!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this problem. Then one suggested by @Nick is decent. You can also check my suggestion.

```
export default function App() {
const data = [
  {
    details: 'Yesterday was his birthday',
    css: true
  },
  {
    details: 'Today is my birthday',
    css: false
  },
  {
    details: 'I cant\'t remember my birthday date',
    css: false
  }
]

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>I need Help</h1>
      <h2>Please How do i style some parts of my rendered details</h2>
      {
        data.map((detail)=>(
          <p className={detail.css ? 'my-custom-class' : ''}>{detail.details}</p>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

With this approach you will not have `<p class="undefined">...</p>`

Comment: That's not how `undefined` works in React. `className={undefined}` will actually result in the DOM element not having a `class` attribute at all, which is desired. I would definitely not recommend setting it to an empty string or else you'll end up with `class=""` in the rendered HTML.

Comment: The two solutions are nice but I really want is something like. I love <span>Football</span/> where the styling will be applicable to the football alone in the first tag